# Local array not being pushed to

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code. The array prices does not seem to be pushed to  the `prices` array despite successfully retrieving the `ustock.unitprice`.

```
getLatestMarketPrices: function(username, callback) {
   var prices = [];
   db.find('portfolio', {user: username}, function(err, stocks) {
     for(var i = 0; i < stocks.length; i++) {
       module.exports.getQuote(stocks[i].stock, function(err, ustock) {
         console.log(ustock.unitprice); // Retrieves 1.092
         prices.push(ustock.unitprice); // Should push to prices array?
       });
     }
   console.log(prices); // Prices is still [] despite earlier push.
   callback(null, prices);
  });
},
```

Is this a scoping issue? I'm not really sure why `prices` is not pushed to.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Is db.find an async call?

Comment: Yes. It has a callback (`function(err, stocks)`). You think I have to callback to the outside array on each iteration? Thanks.

Comment: It's because the `console.log` is called before `getQuote()` has has finished.

Comment: @Andy But a [] array is returned in the last callback. I'm listening over a WebSocket on client side and the array returned is still blank.

Comment: As @Andy says your console.log(prices) call is running before your asynchronous method has completed it tasks and pushed all the values into the array.

Comment: Hmmm. I see. What @Andy says is still true even if last callback still returns `null, []`. Do I have to use `async`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know jquery, you could try deferred object

```
getLatestMarketPrices: function(username, callback) {
   var prices = [];

   var defer = $.Deferred();
  //Attach a handler to be called when the deferred object is resolved
   defer.done(function(){
      console.log(prices); 
      callback(null, prices);
   });

   db.find('portfolio', {user: username}, function(err, stocks) {
     for(var i = 0; i < stocks.length; i++) {
       module.exports.getQuote(stocks[i].stock, function(err, ustock) {
         console.log(ustock.unitprice); // Retrieves 1.092
         prices.push(ustock.unitprice); // Should push to prices array?
         //resolve when we retrieve all
         if (prices.length == stocks.length){
             defer.resolve();  
         }
       });
     }

  });
},
```

Update: or don't need deferred object at all:

```
getLatestMarketPrices: function(username, callback) {
       var prices = [];

       db.find('portfolio', {user: username}, function(err, stocks) {
         for(var i = 0; i < stocks.length; i++) {
           module.exports.getQuote(stocks[i].stock, function(err, ustock) {
             console.log(ustock.unitprice); // Retrieves 1.092
             prices.push(ustock.unitprice); // Should push to prices array?

             //callback only when we receive all 
             if (prices.length == stocks.length){
                 console.log(prices); 
                 callback(null, prices); 
             }
           });
         }

      });
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, Khanh. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: @Sam Saint-Pettersen: I made some adjustments

Comment: Thank you. Tried with defer before your update just now and it worked. :)

Comment: And works without I can confirm. Defer is interesting to know about though; so even though I reduce lines of code I might keep the other way in the comments.  Thanks again. ;)